# ERROR: Could not build wheels for ripser, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pycharm, installation-package

I'm trying yo install ripser (https://ripser.scikit-tda.org) in PyCharm 2021.2.3 (Community Edition) on a macOS Big Sur (version 11.6). I'm using a virtual envirorment with Python 3.8 where I've updated all the packages including wheels and pip.. Any Advice?

```
(venv) (base) Federicos-MBP:TESI federicolot$ pip install ripser
Collecting ripser
  Using cached ripser-0.6.1.tar.gz (72 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting Cython
  Using cached Cython-0.29.24-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: persim in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ripser) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ripser) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ripser) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ripser) (1.21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from persim->ripser) (3.5.0rc1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from persim->ripser) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: deprecated in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from persim->ripser) (1.2.13)
Requirement already satisfied: hopcroftkarp in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from persim->ripser) (1.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from scikit-learn->ripser) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt<2,>=1.10 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from deprecated->persim->ripser) (1.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->persim->ripser) (4.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools-scm>=4 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->persim->ripser) (6.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->persim->ripser) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->persim->ripser) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->persim->ripser) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->persim->ripser) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->persim->ripser) (21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->persim->ripser) (2.8.2)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.2.1
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib->persim->ripser) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tomli>=1.0.0 in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from setuptools-scm>=4->matplotlib->persim->ripser) (1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/federicolot/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from setuptools-scm>=4->matplotlib->persim->ripser) (58.5.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: ripser
  WARNING: Building wheel for ripser failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/federicolot/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/99'
Failed to build ripser
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ripser, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have access permission issue:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/federicolot/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/99'
```

Open the terminal as administrator and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem just now on a fresh box, and it looks like I fixed it.  I am not sure from your question whether it is the **exact** same problem you faced, but I'll walk you through what I did and maybe it will help you or someone else in the future.

---

## Use a venv for testing

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
mkdir ~/test
cd ~/test
python3 -m venv test/foo-venv
source foo-venv/bin/activate
```

## Check the verbose output

... and look for the top most error message. It is usually some kind of compiled C dependency managed via apt-get w/ python.

```
(foo-venv) chris@home:~/test$ pip install -v ripser

...
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed: No such file or directory
...
```

## Try fixing it

Don't get intimidated by the situation. All of it is easy if you know it. Some people just try s#!t, and it is as easy as it sounds.

```
apt-cache search x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
# nada

# ok, I'm going to try some s#!t anyway
apt-get install gcc
```

## If Error Changes,  Keep Going

```
(foo-venv) chris@home:~/test$ pip install -v ripser

...
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: No such file or directory
...
```

Alright, the error changed.

```
# maybe the basics aren't on the box
apt-get install g++ build-essential
```

## Never Give Up, Never Surrender

```
(foo-env) chris@home:~/test$ pip install -v ripser

...
  ripser/pyRipser.cpp:54:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     54 | #include "Python.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
...
```

Great! I see python, and it's a header file. It's probably in a missing lib.

```
apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file find Python.h | grep lib

...
libpython3.11-dev # this looks like a winner
...
```

## For the Win

```
apt-get install libpython3.11-dev
```

```
(foo-venv) chris@home:~/test$ pip install -v ripser

...
Installing collected packages: Cython, ripser
Successfully installed Cython-3.0.6 ripser-0.6.4
```

---

Hope this helps.